# Flask-migrate (alembic) only detects changes in public schema

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic

I have multiple schemas in my database, and several models per schema. Flask-migrate (which is Alembic) is unable to detect changes in any schema besides the public schema. Running

`flask db migrate`

followed by

`flask db upgrade`

will yield an error every time because the tables are already created. How can I configure alembic to recognize other schemas besides the public schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your env.py file created by Alembic so that the `context.configure` function is called using the `include_schemas=True` option. Ensure that this is done in both your offline and online functions.

Here are my modified `run_migrations_offline` and `run_migrations_online` functions.

```
def run_migrations_offline():
    """Run migrations in 'offline' mode.

    This configures the context with just a URL
    and not an Engine, though an Engine is acceptable
    here as well.  By skipping the Engine creation
    we don't even need a DBAPI to be available.

    Calls to context.execute() here emit the given string to the
    script output.

    """
    url = config.get_main_option("sqlalchemy.url")
    context.configure(
        url=url, target_metadata=get_metadata(), literal_binds=True, include_schemas=True
    )

    with context.begin_transaction():
        context.run_migrations()


def run_migrations_online():
    """Run migrations in 'online' mode.

    In this scenario we need to create an Engine
    and associate a connection with the context.

    """

    # this callback is used to prevent an auto-migration from being generated
    # when there are no changes to the schema
    # reference: http://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/cookbook.html
    def process_revision_directives(context, revision, directives):
        if getattr(config.cmd_opts, 'autogenerate', False):
            script = directives[0]
            if script.upgrade_ops.is_empty():
                directives[:] = []
                logger.info('No changes in schema detected.')

    connectable = get_engine()

    with connectable.connect() as connection:
        context.configure(
            connection=connection,
            target_metadata=get_metadata(),
            process_revision_directives=process_revision_directives,
            **current_app.extensions['migrate'].configure_args,
            include_schemas=True
        )

        with context.begin_transaction():
            context.run_migrations()
```